# just missing something small from this client server socket script

Tags: python

here is what i need to do

Write python programs that uses the socket module.
Write a client and a server.
The client will read in an integer and send that integer to the server.
The server will test if the integer is prime and return True or False to the client.
The server will also print that it received the integer, and what integer it received.
The client will then report (for example)
“The servers says that 17 is prime” or
“The servers says that 18 is not prime”
The client then asks for another integer to test.
This continues until the user enters 0.

and here is what i have so far

server script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

tcpsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

tcpsocket.bind( ("0.0.0.0", 8000) ) 

tcpsocket.listen(2) 

(client, (ip,port) ) = tcpsocket.accept()

value = int(client.recv(2048))

MESSAGE1 = "The number %s is not a prime number" %value
MESSAGE2 = "The number %s is a prime number" %value

print "received connection from %s" %ip

print " port is number %d" %port

print " number value received is number %d" %value

for i in range(2,value):
    if (value % i) == 0:
        client.send(MESSAGE1)
else:
        client.send(MESSAGE2)
```

client side

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

import sys

tcpsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 


num = []

while num != 0 :
    num = raw_input("Enter number: ")
    tcpsocket.connect( ('192.168.233.132', 8000) ) 
    tcpsocket.send(num)
    print tcpsocket.recv(2048)
    tcpsocket.close()
```

so this seems to work ok for one number but when i put in the loop then it asks for  a second number but i then get this error

```
Enter number: 3
The number 3 is a prime number
Enter number: 2
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./socketclient.py", line 14, in <module>
    tcpsocket.connect( ('192.168.233.132', 8000) ) 
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
    socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I am close enough but need it to keep running until the user enters 0

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues.

First, your server is only accepting one connection, but your client is trying to make a new connection every time through its loop. So the first iteration of the loop works, but the server is never going to accept another connection. You could fix this, by moving your `tcpsocket.connect()` to before the loop, but then you could run into the second issue.

The second issue is that TCP sends data as a byte stream. Data can be received in differently sized chunks than it is send. For example, if your loop executes `tcpsocket.send('3')` and then `tcpsocket.send('5')`, the server's call to `client.receive(2048)` could return '35'. (With the client you have above, this is unlikely because of the delay in the calling `send` due to using human input, but your server shouldn't depend on this.) Also, a send of '12345' could be received as '123' and then '45'. For TCP, you need to define some protocol for detecting the end of a message. Using a line feed char as a delimiter is a common one.

Comment: i moved the connect to before the loop on the client side and still getting the error after 2nd iteration

Comment: Are you still closing the tcpsocket? You need to move that until after the loop